# Why is the direct product of modules not a module?

Tags: modules

My book says the following:

> Let $M $ and $N $ be modules. Then $M\times N $ is not a module.

I don't understand this statement. It seems to satisfy all properties of modules.

Comment: Are we talking about modules over a commutative ring or over a non-commutative ring? Because in the non-commutative case, the product of a right module and a left module doesn't necessarily have a well-defined module structure.

Comment: @Arthur- I was also thinking scalar product might not be well defined. Let us take $(m, n)-(m, n) $. Is this equal to $(m, n)+(-m, n) $?

Comment: I don't understand the statement either. If you take the product of two left modules, you get a left module - the category of left modules over a fixed ring, commutative or otherwise, forms an abelian category, which includes finite products.

Comment: You can make it a module with proper definitions but as pointed out, the general case is not necciserly so

Comment: Which book are you talking about? More context might help resolve what the book means.

Comment: Dear @MattSamuel : that does not work for unital modules, at least. You would have $(2m,n)=2(m,n)=(m,n)+(m,n)$, and subtracting from both sides yields $(m,0)=(m,n)$, an absurdity if $n\neq 0$. Regards